# Put date widget behind subject of lock screen iOS 16

Tags: iphone, ios

I have seen people put the date/time widgets behind the subject of their lock screen (usually a person). How do I do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible since it'd also block the time. You have to move the photo down.

Comment: @Ezekiel I am talking about the actual wallpaper photo. I don't know how (probably the same AI powering some of the other background removal features), but you could have say, a selfie wallpaper, where the time is behind the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it must be a photo taken with 'Portrait' switched on. This would already have the necessary masks in place to enable this further separation.

In order for it to work, you have to select your screen image from the 'people' list, not 'photos'.

This from [MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/ios-16-lock-screen/)

> **People**
>
> As the name suggests, tapping on the "People" category will bring up images of people that you've photographed that will work well with a new depth effect that the Lock Screen supports. On select images, the time will go under the person or object in the photo to create a layered look, similar to how Portrait mode photos look on the Apple Watch.
>
> [image]
>
> Once you choose a person to feature on your Lock Screen, you'll see how it will look with the time depth effect. You can opt to leave the photo natural or add Studio, Black and White, or customizable Color Backdrop options, which are available depending on the photo you're using.

<sup>I can't test this yet, I always wait for the dust to settle before committing to a new OS</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[Cool depth effect wallpapers for iOS 16 Lock Screen in 2022](https://www.igeeksblog.com/depth-effect-wallpapers-for-iphone-lock-screen/)

1. **Unlock** your iPhone with Touch ID or Face ID.
2. Make sure you **stay on the Lock Screen**.
3. Tap **Customize**.
4. Now, tap the **three dots** at the bottom right.
5. Make sure **Depth Effect** has a tick mark next to it.

***Note:*** Even after enabling the Depth Effect, it may not work on some images since iOS 16 still needs some polishing.

Comment: Also make sure there are no widgets in the slots below the time. If there are, "Depth Effect" will be disabled in order to prevent these widgets from being obscured by the front person/object in the photo.